# Kendo date picker custom date format

Tags: datepicker, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-validator

I have an application which allows the customer to set the date format by setting screen.
I change the current thread culture date format, and set the date and parsing format in the kendo date picker.

```
  DateTimeFormatInfo datetimeFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
  datetimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm tt"; //(set static for testing)
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat = datetimeFormat;
```

My problem is when I change the date format a client side validation error returns says that the field should be a date.
I tried to set custom rule in the kendo validator but that not helps me because when I change the date this rule not fired.

```
$("myForm").kendoValidator(
                {
                    rules: {
                       dateValidation: function(input)
                        {
                            if (input.is("[data-role=datepicker]")) {
                                // My code should be here
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
}});
```

Anyone can help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to add custom rule you need to set the custom format in the kendo validator as following:

```
kendo.ui.validator.rules.mvcdate = function (input) {
return input.val() === "" || kendo.parseDate(input.val(), "dd/MM/yyyy") !== null;
}
```

This code will return true (valid) if the date picker has a value and the value is in the correct format (dd/MM/yyyy in the above)